# Python 3: How to judge if the given function can be called successfully (i.e. reach the first line of the function body) with the given arguments?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a function `f`. It takes a function `g` and a set of `*args` and `**kwargs` as input. It's supposed to call the input function `g` with the arguments and return its result. One requirement: if the given arguments are not accepted by the function, I should raise a custom exception instead of letting python trigger it's own `TypeError`. How do I know that the given arguments cannot be used to call the given function successfully?

Example:

```
def f(g, *args, **kwargs):
    # How to implement bad_arguments()?
    if bad_arguments(g, *args, **kwargs):
        raise CustomTypeError()
    else:
        return g(*args, **kwargs)
```

My first guess is to use the `inspect` module. I know I can look at all the expected arguments by inspecting the function. But then how do I determine whether or not the provided arguments fulfill the requirement, specially considering there might be variable args (i.e. `*args` and `**kwargs`) in `g`'s signature and the calling arguments might specify positional arguments by names. It seems complicated enough to me that manual logic just seem to be unreliable here.

**EDIT**

Please see my comments to this question. I hope they clarify my question a bit more.

Also, to ask the question in a different way: you know how python checks the arguments before actually invoking your function body and raises `TypeError` if it finds something mismatching (e.g. when an argument is not provided, or when a named parameter which is not on the argument list is provided)? I basically want to do the same logic here then raise my `CustomTypeError`.

** EDIT in reply to @SigmaPiEpsilon:**

I seemed to have found a bug in your example code (which is totally fine considering it was just an example to illustrate your idea).

My point being, manual reproduction of this standard python logic might be erroneous. And that's why I prefer a more systematic way, if you will.

```
from inspect import signature

def check_args(f, *args, **kwargs):
    sig = signature(f)
    parameters = {"POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD" : [], "KEYWORD_ONLY" : []}
    for elem in sig.parameters.values():
        parameters[str(elem.kind)].append(elem.name)
    print(parameters)
    if len(args) > len(parameters["POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD"]):
        print("More positional arguments")
    elif len(kwargs) != len(parameters["KEYWORD_ONLY"]):
        print("Insufficient keyword arguments")
    elif set(kwargs.keys()) != set(parameters["KEYWORD_ONLY"]):
        print("Provided keywords %s does not match function keywords %s" %(list(kwargs.keys()),parameters["KEYWORD_ONLY"]))
    else:
        z,u = f(*args,**kwargs)


def f(x, y, z, kw="Hello"):
    u = x + y
    v = x/y
    print(z)
    print(kw)

    return z, u


f(3, 4, 5, kw='a')
check_args(f, 3, 4, 5, kw='a')
```

The output is:

```
$ python test.py
5
a
{'POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'kw'], 'KEYWORD_ONLY': []}
Insufficient keyword arguments
```

Comment: The function `f` seems pointless to me. You should just call `g(*args, **kwargs)`. If the arguments are bad, `g` should complain by raising an exception.

Comment: In other words: You determine whether the arguments are bad by calling `g`.

Comment: Of course, if you have a specific function `g` in mind, you should mention that in your question, and probably the answer would be "read the documentation of `g`".

Comment: I intentionally omitted useful part of `f` from this question, because they are not relevant.

Comment: I don't think calling `g` will help here. Because even if `g` raises `TypeError`, how would you know it's because the arguments are bad? Maybe `g` can raise `TypeError` for some other internal reason. My goal is to raise my `CustomTypeError` when the provided arguments don't fullfill the signature of the function `g`.

Comment: I don't have a specific `g` in mind. As you can see clearly from the problem statement, `g` is provided by the called of `f`, and it can be any function.

Comment: @Roy Check my recent edit. This seems to be closer to what you want. My previous edit will apply if you want more customization though.

Comment: Thanks @SigmaPiEpsilon. `Signature.bind()` is exactly I was looking for. //thumbs-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult problem to solve generally due to the flexibility of python function arguments (positional, keywords, keyword only etc). As such it is probably better to solve specific cases that suits your applications. For details look into python [Signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) and [Parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) objects of python `inspect` module. A crude example is provided below to illustrate one approach that uses the `bind()` method of the signature object. You can adapt this to fit your specific example.

Edit: Added a version of the check in line with OP's requirement. Check previous edits for more customized checking of arguments

```
from inspect import signature

def check_args(f, *args, **kwargs):

    sig = signature(f)
    try:
        bound = sig.bind(*args,**kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def f(g, *args, **kwargs):

    if not check_args(g, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception("Bad Arguments")
    else:
        return g(*args, **kwargs)


def g(x, y,*,z,kw="Hello"):
    u = x + y
    v = x*y
    print(z)
    print(kw)

    return u

f(g,3,4,z = 5, kw = "Hello")
```

Test in python 3.4

```
$ python3.4 -i function_check2.py 
5
Hello
>>> f(g,3,4,5,z = 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "function_check2.py", line 16, in f
    raise Exception("Bad Arguments")
Exception: Bad Arguments
>>> f(g,3,4,z = 5)                                                        
5
Hello
7
>>> f(g,3,4,kw = "Hello")                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "function_check2.py", line 16, in f
    raise Exception("Bad Arguments")
Exception: Bad Arguments
```

Comment: Can I assume that you are suggesting we manually reproduce the logic python already does for every function call? I was hoping that we can have something more systematic (like calling an existing library or built-in call). I fear that manual reproduction might not be 100% accurate.

Comment: Please kindly to my updated question for a case which seemed to break your example.

Comment: You missed the '*' in the function definition in your code `def f(x, y, z, kw="Hello")` should be `def f(x, y, *, z, kw="Hello")`. The `*` signals end of positional arguments. Anything after that is considered keyword only arguments. Check [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Comment: As I understood from your question you want to customize the error messages that python returns when function arguments don't match. This is a difficult problem to solve generally due to the variable syntax and I'm not aware of any tools that solves the problem generally (I would like to know that). But if you want to take customized actions in specific cases like when no keyword argument is provided or more positional arguments are provided, the approach outlined is a way to do that. Instead of the print statements in my code you can add your own code and deal with the cases separately.

Comment: An example will be to subclass the python exceptions `TypeError` and `SyntaxError` that python will normally raise and create your own custom exception class based on something similar as the if statements and provide more customized error messages to the user with additional information.